# Javascript/jQuery breaks the formatting of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

The formatting of my page is incorrect when I add the following code:

```
$('#Inventory_accountNumber').blur(function(){
    var accounts = $(this).val();
    accounts = accounts.replace(/-/g,'');
    var accountNum = [];
    accountNum = accounts.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<accountNum.length;i++) {
        var newstr = '';
        if(accountNum[i].length == 24) {
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(0,4) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(4,7) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(7,10) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(10,14) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(14,20) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(20,24) + '-';
            newstr += '0000-000';
            accountNum[i] = newstr;
        }
        else if(accountNum[i].length == 31) {
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(0,4) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(4,7) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(7,10) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(10,14) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(14,20) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(20,24) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(24,28) + '-';
            newstr += accountNum[i].substring(28,31);
            accountNum[i] = newstr;
        }
    }
    accountNum.join(',');
    $(this).val(accountNum);

});
```

The jsfiddle illustrates this code in use: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lwv4U/14/

As you can see, it works in the jsfiddle, but on the live formatting issues are present. The screenshots below depict the page with and without the code added. This code is the only change in the code between the two code bases. If it matters Yii is being used as a framework.

**Before**
[image: before]

**After**
[image: after]

Comment: you should see if you have any errors on the console that prevents the execution of other scripts

Comment: @svillamayor There are no errors in the console that is my issue.

Comment: I think you should provide more information around your HTML code, script, etc for people to help you.

Comment: Use firebug to inspect the css classes assigned to your accordian divs before and after. Are you using the jQuery UI for this?

Comment: also please confirm that this is happening upon page load when the script is present, and not just when the blur function executes. Where is this code in relation to the accordion code, above or below?

Comment: @WebChemist yes this is happening on page load. The error is related to this added code in some way as the problem only is present when I have the code there. And yes, jquery ui is being used for this. The code is right after the accordion code, though when I put it above it the result is still similar.

Comment: @WebChemist It seems despite where I add the code, the accordion classes are always missing many css elements that should normally be applied to them. Upon removing the code the CSS is implemented correctly.

Comment: what happens if you comment out everything inside the function, from  var accounts = $(this).val(); to $(this).val(accountNum); ?

Comment: @WebChemist the page loads as expected; normally with no issues.

Comment: I guess just keep commenting out less and less of the code inside the blur function until you find the line(s) that are causing it and report back if that doesn't give you the clue you need to solve this...

Comment: @WebChemist As soon as line 5 is added is when it seems to break it. Now this is using Yii, so if there is an error it seems like the whole section of Javascript here is not being processed, therefore I am thinking there is something wrong with line 5 that may be causing this issue. Is there any issue relating to the split method? I am on v1.6.1 of jquery. (By line 5 I am referring to line 5 in the jsfiddle)

Comment: Should have asked sooner, but this happens in all browsers right? Might not be able to help without seeing all the other html and js. Your split looks fine, although you don't need [], split will create the array. I optimized your script here http://jsfiddle.net/Lwv4U/21/

Comment: @WebChemist Thank you for optimizing this, I thought what I was doing seemed a little clunky, especially when looking at the substrings that were there like crazy. I will test this on Tuesday when the weekend is over and get back to you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwv4U/24/  another modification to @WebChemist optimized version. Catches non-digit characters, and formats any length string.

Comment: @Daniel But does this account for commas in the code?

Comment: Yes all non-digit characters are removed from the string.  Then the string is parsed.

Comment: @Daniel if the length equals 9 the string should not be reformatted though.

Comment: That wasn't expressed in the initial question.  http://jsfiddle.net/Lwv4U/25/  Strings 9 or less have no formating

Comment: @Daniel my problems are resolved when using this. Maybe you'd like to submit this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle.net/Lwv4U/25

JS:

```
$('#Inventory_accountNumber').blur(function(){
  $(this).val(function(index, value){
    var str = value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
    if (str.length < 10) return str;  
    return str.match(/(\d{4})?(\d{3})?(\d{3})?(\d{4})?(\d{6})?(\d{4})?(\d{4})?(\d+)?/)
    .slice(1).join("-").replace(/\-+/g,'-');
  });
});
```